# Generate schema for a analysis services database project

Tags: ssis, ssas, bids

I was given a task to have a better understanding of several ETL packages that were created in a Database project using Business Intelligence Development Studio(SQL 2005).

Currently I have to open each master package, package and then data flow and so on to discover the relationships that exists with either the source tables and the destination tables.

I realized that probably a good way to more easily get that information would be having a tool similar to what SchemaSpy does with a normal Database. That would provide my a high level detail of the relationships that exist.

Anyone knows an application/script that could help me achieving this result?

I tried to search, but I must admit that I was getting the feeling that I wasn't really searching in the right direction as most of my searches ended up pointing for database comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, the only way I found to do this was to parse the xml inside the packages and extract the relationships. And then using  Graphviz (the same visual component used by schema spy) create the diagrams.

Unfortunately this was an expensive thing to do and I never finished the project. Mainly due to lack of knowledge around the xml structure but it is definitely possible to be achieved